# OpenID Connect: How to add claims data in client credential flow

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, clientcredential

Is it possible to add a custom claims data in the client credentials flow with OpenID Connect?

If yes, can u please tell me how it can be done.

I'm working on setting up client credential flow to a service for a mobile application to communicate get the access token via token endpoint. Here i need to generate the token with each user login data in the JWT claims.

Please suggest if there are better flows to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenID Connect: How to add custom claims data in the client credential flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608289/openid-connect-how-to-add-custom-claims-data-in-the-client-credential-flow)

Comment: @JanGaraj No. It doesn't answer how to pass claims data with client credential flow